# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind') useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js

I have this code right here

```
import React from "react";

import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    getMovies {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;

function Home() {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

  if (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and when I'm running it I get lots of errors in my console. I'm not sure what I’m doing wrong.

[image: Picture of wrrors]

I can tell it's caused by how useQuery is used i think. I'm not sure what's wrong though.

thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem today, the way of `useQuery` that you used is correct.

This is my original code in `ApolloProvider` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';

const httpLink = new createHttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:5000"
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

export default(
    <ApolloProvider client={ client }>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
)
```

I found using `apollo-client` dependency would cause the errors. Then I changed it and installed `@apollo/client` at **3.5.10** version instead to import `ApolloClient`. And It finally works fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
// import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';
```

In addition, I've also tried to use `@apollo/client` at the newest version. It worked successfully as well.

Comment: I did the same, but also had to upgrade @apollo/react-hooks (I upgraded both packages to the newest)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is in the GraphQL schema, you are missing **query** in it. Try using the following schema:

```
const FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    getMovies {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem because of an old tutorial.

I configured my Apollo client in the wrong way.

Do the same as described in the [get started guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/) from graphql and it will work perfect.